# Error adding sprites using addchild method: argument must to be non-nil

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, addchild

I've a problem using the method addchild adding sprites

previously I've never had this problem and I could add png files without problems,now sometimes if I try to add some sprites to the scene using the addchild method I receive these errors:

*[2126:15503] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. cgImage is nil*

[2126:15503] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:image_1.png in CCTextureCache

[2126:15503] *** Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:]

I think that the problem isn't in the code because if I try to add sprites using the images included in the default Cocos2d project it works... I receive this error only from some images...also if I've added it by the same way to the project and to the scene, what could be the cause?

I receive this error also using the default helloWorldLayer class, without changing anything, only adding

```
CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite SpriteWithFile: @"image_1.png"];
[self addChild:sprite];
```

the rest of the code is exactly the same of the default HelloWorldLayer class
there could be something that might cause this error in some png files?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would probably make it easier for others to help you, if you posted some of the code that you have already written.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I've edited the question...I think that the problem can't be in the code because using the same code and changing  the image name with a default image or others it works4

Answer (score 3):

Add image_1.png to your Xcode project. Make sure you use the exact same filename, for example Image_1.PNG won't load on devices due to uppercasing.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tried to re-save the png file from the psd one and now it works but maybe I did some errors writing the sprite names.